# Ember PODS structure and Ember engine

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons, ember-engines

Can using the Ember PODS structure cause any issues while integrating with the Ember engine ?

What is the recommended structure; PODS or traditional structure ?

Comment: By engines do you mean the [Engines RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/10)?

Comment: I don't know the state of engines but even in the latest betas/canary I don't think you have any of that. I can point you [to this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wc3a_ttTy0/) by core team member robert jackson regarding the state of pods, but I don't think he addresses that subject.

I prefer pods, as such I would use them, but I have no idea what it will mean for engines.

Comment: It just landed in canary. https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines

After reading the code engines seems to use same resolvers so pods should work like it does with addons. The final pod structure will get its own resolver anyway and shouldn't affect engines.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using pod structure. For today (March 21, 2017), we're using in-repo engines with Ember 2.8 LTS, and pod structure working well for our case.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pod structure is supported in ember engines.  After setting up your engine, you would run:

`ember g component my-component --pod`

The traditional approach is also supported.